# Uncaught ReferenceError: openForm is not defined at HTMLDivElement.onclick

Tags: angular, typescript, button, onclick

This error appears when I click on it, I don't know what's wrong with the code, I'm begginig with TS and Angular, I have no syntaxis error, just when i run it appers this on the console "Uncaught ReferenceError: openForm is not defined at HTMLDivElement.onclick"

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.scss']
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {


  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }


  }
const button = document.getElementById('mainButton');

      const openForm = function() {
      button.className = 'active';
    };

    this.checkInput = function(input) {
      if (input.value.length > 0) {
        input.className = 'active';
      } else {
        input.className = '';
      }
    };

    const closeForm = function() {
      button.className = '';
    };

    document.addEventListener('keyup', function(e) {
      if (e.keyCode === 27 || e.keyCode === 13) {
        closeForm();
      }
    });
```

```html
<body>
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:400,500,300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<div id="mainButton">
 <div class="btn-text" onclick="openForm()">Sign In</div>
 <div class="modal">
  <div class="close-button" onclick="closeForm()">x</div>
  <div class="form-title">Sign In</div>
  <div class="input-group">
   <input type="text" id="name" onblur="checkInput(this)" />
   <label for="name">Username</label>
  </div>
  <div class="input-group">
   <input type="password" id="password" onblur="checkInput(this)" />
   <label for="password">Password</label>
  </div>
  <div class="form-button" onclick="closeForm()">Go</div>
  <div class="codepen-by">CodePen by Cole Waldrip</div>
 </div>
</div>
<div class="codepen-by">CodePen by Cole Waldrip</div>
</body>
```